# What's the logical value of "string" in Python?

Tags: python, string, casting, boolean

I erroneously wrote this code in Python:

```
name = input("what is your name?")
if name == "Kamran" or "Samaneh":
    print("That is a nice name")
else:
    print("You have a boring name ;)")
```

It always prints out "That is a nice name" even when the input is neither "Kamran" nor "Samaneh".

Am I correct in saying that it considers "Samaneh" as a true? Why?

By the way, I already noticed my mistake. The correct form is:

```
if name == "Kamran" or name == "Samaneh":
```

Comment: This should not have been linked as a duplicate for the "how do I write this `if` statement" canonical, because OP **already understood** how, and was asking a question about **why** the result of the wrong code is as it is. The question was specific about the details of how the code is evaluated, in a way that isn't directly addressed by that canonical. It is, however, addressed by a **different** canonical. (Fortunately, there aren't too many things that have been incorrectly closed as duplicates of **this** one....)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any non empty string in Python (and most other languages) is true as are all non-zero numbers and non-empty lists, dictionaries, sets and tuples.<sup>1</sup>

A nicer way to do what you want is:

```
name = input("what is your name?")
if name in ("Kamran", "Samaneh"):
    print("That is a nice name")
else:
    print("You have a boring name ;)")
```

This creates a tuple containing the names that you want and performs a membership test.

<sup>1 As delnan points out in the comments, this applies to all *well written* collections. That is, if you implement a custom collection class, make sure that it is false when it's empty.</sup>

Comment: Not only lists, dicts and tuples -- *all* empty collections (if well-written).

Comment: @delnan, I was trying to think of a good way to say that so I stuck to the built ins and forgot sets.

Comment: Most objects, collection or otherwise, are truthy; only the ones wheich are explicitly define otherwise aren’t. If you just define a class with `class C(): pass`, instances will test as `True`.

Answer (score 8):

Besides the empty string `''`, strings will all evaluate to `True` (see [this page for a full list of values of all types that evaluate to `False`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). This follows the logic of many other programming languages (except some which also evaluate strings like `'0'`, `'false'`, etc. to `False`). The exact decision of what to do is somewhat arbitrary, but the choice made can be explained as allowing the cast to be used as a simple way to test for empty (default, or unpopulated) strings.

You can always force a cast of any type to `bool` using the `bool()` function.

```
>>> bool('')
False
>>> bool('non-empty string')
True
>>> bool('0')
True
>>> bool('False')
True
>>> bool('false')
True
```

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

"....All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true."

Answer (score 2):

In Python an empty string is considered `False`, `True` otherwise.

You could use the `in` operator:

```
if name in ("Kamran","Samaneh"):
    print("That is a nice name")
else:
    print("You have a boring name ;)")
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-empty string is True, yes. An empty one is False. This is super-handy.