# Python "or" usage with "in" statement

Tags: python, logical-operators

I've this code:

```
url='http://mybeautifulurl.com'

('h' or 'f') in url[0:4] #This is True
('f' or 'h') in url[0:4] #This is False
```

I'm just trying to understand why the 'or' operator seems to evaluate just the first condition.

Comment: Python is not English. Your condition must be `'h' in ... or 'f' in ...`. (Or some alternative check which allows you to express that in one go.)

Comment: hint: try running content inside the parenthesis by itself in the interpreter. maybe experiment with empty strings and 'and' operator as well.

Comment: Question has been marked has duplicated and it is; it has nothing to do with 'in' statement as even the following code is evaluated false:
    'h' == ('f' or 'h')

Answer (score 4):

This `or` returns the first element if it evaluates to true (as a bool) and the second one otherwise... it's is usually applied to set default values.

This way, `'h' or 'f'` is simply `'h'` and `'f' or 'h'` is simply `'f'`.

You can achieve what you want with something like:

```
any(x in url[:4] for x in ['h', 'f'])
```

Comment: If you are trying to generalize this you may want to look into more efficient operations, e.g.:
`not set(['h', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'awefw']).isdisjoint(url[:400])

Comment: Even the following code is evaluated false:
`'h' == ('f' or 'h')`. I voted for below answer -but score didn't increment as question is duplicated. Other very useful answer can be found at suggested [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870378/python-or-operator-weird-behavior) or even [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531794/whats-the-logical-value-of-string-in-python).

Comment: @cinv3 `'h' == ('h' or 'f')` evaluates to true (note the order between `'h'` and `'f'`).